# How do I fix my monitor?

Tags: display

[image]

My monitor is acting up. And i did recently moved and have ruled out that its the monitor itself not data coming in as even the system menu shows this kind of flickering lines.

Weird thing was that for a good while it was fine and then it started acting this way and hasnt stopped.

Id rather not go buy a new monitor because then id have to buy two new ones :/.

Comment: Take the monitor to a local repair shop as they can test before you replace it.

Comment: Any idea what this issue is called? Cant really call it flickering right?

Comment: Backlight flickering, parts on monitor board, power supply intermittent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took it to get this repaired and the technician resoldered the connection of the motherboard to the graphics board?
Something along the lines of just resoldering everything and he called the issue as intermittent lines.